# Why does relativistic kinetic energy (KE) equal to the total relativistic energy minus the rest mass energy?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

OK, I understand why $KE=\gamma mc^2-mc^2$, but why is it also equal to $E-E_0$?

Comment: have a look at the answers to this question - see if that is helpful.... http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143652/

Comment: What is $E$ and what is $E_0$?

Comment: @Sofia typically $E$ is total energy and $E_0$ is rest mass energy - the question I linked has a good discussion about different ways of expressing these values and particularly $m$ and $m_0$

Comment: Welcome @Max - nice question - you might want to look at how to put equations and symbols into your questions with latex type codes MathJax - see for example http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is that if we start with

$$KE = \gamma mc^2 - m c^2$$

then because $mc^2$ is the rest mass energy. $E_0$

$$ E_0 = m c^2 $$

and the total energy $E$ is given by

$$ E = \gamma m C^2 $$

so substituting into your first equation gives

$$ KE = E - E_0 $$

does this help?

Comment: OK, but I think the equation for the rest mass energy is derived from the one I don't understand. If not, then please give me the derivation of the equation you've used

Comment: $E=mc^2$ is pretty fundamental and I really suggest that you look at this question to see where it comes from --- http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143652/is-e2-mc22pc2-correct-or-is-e-mc2-the-correct-one -- there are some really good answers there given by people who probably understand it better than I do - I have an answer there too, but it is not as detailed as some of the others. - Comment back here again if that does not help and we can take it from there

Comment: I don't think so as the equation for the relativistic kinetic energy was discovered far earlier than the $E=mc^2$ one. Unfortunately, the question on the link you gave me doesn't provide with the derivation nor any information about $E=mc^2$

Comment: @Max sorry it did not help - i am not sure if the following link is interesting as a step towards what you are looking for http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2011/aug/23/did-einstein-discover-e-equals-mc-squared  ... or perhaps here? https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/einstein-did-not-derive-e-mc2-first.28362/

Answer (score 2):

If you take the non-(special)-relativistic limit of that expression you find that
$$\text{KE} \approx \left(\frac12mv^2 + mc^2\right) - mc^2$$
which is what you would expect from classical mechanics. The other way to see this is that, when a particle is at rest in a certain inertial frame of reference, its relativistic energy is given by its rest mass through $m_0c^2$. This represent a sort of *frozen* energy contained inside the body. Kinetic energy is then extra energy the body gains when it aquires a certain velocity.

Comment: Why does the rest mass energy equal to $m_0c^2$?

Comment: it comes from $E = \gamma m_0c^0$

Answer (score 1):

Relativistic kinetic energy is defined as $E-E_0$ because this definition naturally follows from the more general definition of relativistic energy as $E = \gamma mc^2$ where $\gamma$ depends upon the velocity.

It then follows to define rest energy for $v=0, \gamma=1$ as $E_0 = mc^2$, and relativistic kinetic energy as the excess energy when its moving over the energy when it's not: $E-E_0 =\gamma mc^2 - mc^2$.

The more fundamental question to then ask is: **why is relativistic energy defined as $E = \gamma mc^2$?**

Energy is defined via [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem)  as that physical quantity that's conserved for a system whose physical laws don't change over time. For a single point particle of mass m

$$E =\gamma mc^2$$

Comment: So what does the theorem state (it didn't say anything about energy in Wikipedia)?

Comment: @Max further down the page under [examples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem#Examples)