# How is it that a gauge boson can contain energy but yet remain massless?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, mass-energy

A gauge boson is said to have no mass and yet it is said to be a force carrier, meaning it is has energy? Given the equivalency of mass and energy how can this be?

Comment: What *equivalency*, exactly? See, e.g. http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143652/50583, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2229/50583

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of above links. No (rest) mass is the important point, not whether we are talking about gluons or photons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term mass (as in "a gauge boson is massless") is currently used to name the invariant rest mass $m_0$, which satisfies the equation $m_0^2=E^2-p^2$ (where $E$ is the energy and $p$ is the three-momentum). The "mass" $m=E$ equivalent to the energy is dependent of the frame of reference and now physicists prefer to just refer to it as energy.

Therefore, a particle with zero mass $m_0=0$ can have nonzero energy if it has some momentum.